# Bootstrap - how to target a specific tooltip?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So on my page I have several tooltips but I'd like the colour of each one to be different. How would I go about doing this? I suppose it'll be possible via a complex route of CSS but I was hoping for something more succinct.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row redbg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"></div>    
<div class="row bluebg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    <script>
    $(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
    </script>
```

**CSS (Just for red at the moment)**

```
/* TOOL TIP */
.tooltip-inner {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}

.tooltip.top .tooltip-arrow {
    border-top-color: red;
}

.tooltip.right .tooltip-arrow {
    border-right-color: red;
}

.tooltip.bottom .tooltip-arrow {
    border-bottom-color: red;
}

.tooltip.left .tooltip-arrow {
    border-left-color: red;
}
.tooltip-inner {
    max-width: 350px;
    /* If max-width does not work, try using width instead */
    width: 350px; 
    height:75px;
```

So how would I make the div with the class `redbg` show a red tooltip and how would the div with the class `bluebg` show a blue tooltip?

Thanks

Comment: Done...........

Comment: you can add a different class for each tooltip on `show.bs.tooltip` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.redbg + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: red;
    color: #fff;
}

.bluebg + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
    background-color: blue;
    color: #fff;
}
```

I think this can achieve what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Test for Bootstrap 4:

You can add data-custom-class attribute on the link and use that class in css to update your tooltip.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="chatbox-chat-icon chattoggler" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-custom-class="chat-tooltip" title="ChatGPT Icon">
      ChatGPT
    </a>
```

CSS:

```
.chat-tooltip .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: green;
}
```